# How apply multiple event on single button?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a button on which i want to set multiple event. When user touch button first time then i have change background image and when user again touch button then reset first image. How do that with button?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i get my answer by this question:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789546/objective-c-one-button-with-multiple-sequential-outcomes if anyone have another answer then i will accepts. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to have multiple events, just call one function and in this function change the background (having some kind of indicator which background to display -> `i` here)

```
- (void)changeBackground {
  i = (i+1)%2;

  if (i == 0)
    // first background
  else 
    // second background    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
    int i = 0;
   -(void) buttonPressed{
       i++;
       if(i == 1){
           //Here load the view which you want to load on first touch to a button
       }
       else{
           //Here load the other view 
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)changeBG {

  BOOL flag = TRUE;

  if (flag == TRUE) {

    // first background
    flag = FLASE;

  } else {

     // second background    
     flag = TRUE;
   }
}
```

Call above method in your buttonTouchUPInside method.

Answer (score 0):

```
in Button action 
-(void)clickOnCheckButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn_tmp=sender;
    if(!(btn_tmp.selected))
    {
        //you can set your image
        [btn_tmp setSelected:YES];
    }
    else {
        //you can set your image
        [btn_tmp setSelected:NO];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try it

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    static int counter;
    if (counter == 0){
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"ONE" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }else if (counter == 1){
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"TWO" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }else if (counter == 2){
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"THREE" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    counter += 1;


    if (counter >2){
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```